# Rails Strong Parameter unpermited parameter for Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters, ruby-grape

I am trying to send on my API endpoint a file. I am validating the inputs with Strong Parameters, so I have:

```
def postParams
  ActionController::Parameters.new(params).permit(:foo, :bar, :cv_file)
end

params do
  requires :foo, allow_blank: false, type: String
  requires :bar, allow_blank: false, type: String
  requires :cv_file, :type => Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile
end
```

And the result for this is `Unpermitted parameter: cv_file`.

If I change type for `cv_file` into String will work but for `Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile` type is not accepting.

Do I miss something? Maybe a header?

**UPDATE**

As I see there wa some problems with my postman, so I make the calls with curl now and I am back to 'Unpermitted parameter: cv_file'.

I see that this problem occur because the file is coming like:

```
<Hashie::Mash filename="CV 2017 June.pdf" head="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cv_file\"; filename=\"CV 2017 June.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" name="cv_file" tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170614-11-1vhzirn.pd‌​f> type="application/octet-stream">
```

and not a `"cv_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile ....`.

Any idea?

**UPDATE 2**

I have found a solution but I don't think it's the best way, but you may understand the problem better with this type of solution:

```
  def postParams

    local_param = params.dup

    upload = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
        tempfile: params[:csv][:tempfile],
        filename: params[:csv][:filename],
        type:     params[:csv][:type],
        headers:  params[:csv][:head],
      )

    local_param[:csv] = upload

    ActionController::Parameters.new(local_param).permit(:foo, :bar, :cv_file)
  end

  desc "Create new candidate"
  params do
    requires :foo, allow_blank: false, type: String
    requires :bar, allow_blank: false, type: String
    optional :cv_file,:type => File
  end
  post 'new' do

    post_params = postParams

    if(post_params[:candidate_cv])

      # Process the CV file
      post_params.delete :candidate_cv
    end

    Candidate.create!(post_params)
  end
```

Comment: Yes, you need the `multipart/form-data` header for the content type. How are you sending it?

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/handling-file-upload-using-ruby-on-rails-5-api

Comment: Hi @Iceman, I tried but I get `Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError (invalid %-encoding ("foo" .......` but yes I see the file there. I send with POSTMAN, maybe this is relevant. https://i.imgur.com/YffC7RM.png

Comment: Seems to be different in CURL, I did not get the `Rack::QueryParser::InvalidParameterError`, but I am back to `Unpermitted parameter: cv_file` . To only way was to not use `postParams` method and I have the file there. `<Hashie::Mash filename="CV Sebastian - Vîrlan 2017 June.pdf" head="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cv_file\"; filename=\"CV Sebastian - V\xC3\xAErlan 2017 June.pdf\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n" name="cv_file" tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170614-11-1vhzirn.pdf> type="application/octet-stream">`. I cannot found a way with strong param.

Comment: You should [edit] your question with this info, to increase the chances of an answer, I'm afraid this is not my strong point in Rails.